# Getting this error “Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS” error?

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query is as follow,

```
DECLARE @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @bcpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @LogText NVARCHAR(250)

SET @logText = (select * from cbstf.AppLog0 WHERE LogDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59')
-- SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "select * from cbstf.AppLog0 " queryout '
SET @FilePath = 'D:\Backup_SQL\'
SET @OutputFile = 'BCPTest.csv'
SET @bcpCommand = @LogText + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

And i get the error message is as follow,

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

My expectation is i can get the file result from query in the CSV or TXT files.

Comment: You can't. See [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/)

Answer (score 0):

You can select only one column in a subquery.
You need to specify a column instead of '*'.